# Is the return type of my 'select' method wrong?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, dao

I am trying to make a simple website.
My goal is to make it possible to insert/select/update/delete customer data using SQL.

While I managed to make the [insert] method work, my select method is not working at all. It seems the return type is wrong but I am not sure...
I'm a beginner in Java, JSP, SQL and everything so maybe I am confusing (again) some basic things?

Can anyone check my code, please?

I tried to change the return type but I never got to find the answer.
So here is my code.

In SQL, I created a table called  to save customer data.
The selectMember method is in the java class
and, evidently, the doGet method is in the survlet.

Thanks in advance!

```
public MemberVO selectMember(MemberVO member) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection();
        String sql = "select * from Member where userid=?";
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            String userid = rs.getString("userid");
            String password = rs.getString("password");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            String address = rs.getString("address");
        }
    }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("MemberDAO.select() : " + e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            closeConnection(con);
        }
    return member;      
    }
```

---

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
    MemberDAO dao = new MemberDAO();
    MemberVO member = new MemberVO();
    if(action.equals("insert")) {
        request.setAttribute("action",  action);

    }else if(action.equals("update")) {
        try {
            member = dao.selectMember(userid); //here I have the red warning
            request.setAttribute("member", member);
            request.setAttribute("action",  action);
        }catch(RuntimeException e) {
            request.setAttribute("message",  e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("/memberform.jsp");
    disp.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: You are taking on quite a technology stack all at once.  I'd recommend that you learn some Java first, and at least the basics of SQL.  Learn something about JDBC next, and only then should you start studying servlets (and JSP, if you wish, but what you present has no JSP in it).

Answer (score 2):

You forget set the condition for `where userid=?`, you need something like:

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt .setString(1, "yourUserId");
```

Answer (score 1):

You never bind any value to the placeholder in your select query.  Try binding a value:

```
con = getConnection();
String sql = "select * from Member where userid = ?";
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setInt(1, member.getId());
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    // process single record
}
```

I am assuming that the `userid` value to bind would be coming from the `MemberVO` object which gets passed into the `selectMember()` method.  I assume that a method called `getId()` exists.

I also assume that `userid` is actually an integer column, not a string column.  If it really be a string column, then bind the value using `Statement#setString`:

```
pstmt.setString(1, member.getId());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed the code as you advised.
Thought it didn't solve the problem :( 
Maybe I didn't post enough code?!

Actually I created a class called <MemberVO> to put the data in.
        private String userid;
 private String name;
 private String password;
 private String email;
 private String address;

Then I used the setters/getters

This is all I put in that class.

Comment: sorry I accidentally clicked on <enter> and I was editing lol

Comment: Then your code is incomplete.  The `MemberVO` object is the only input into the method running the select query, and that query needs some value to bind for the `userid`.  So, you need to think of what you can change to make this work.